# Is a single Zalgo character considered a single character?

Tags: discussion, policy, characters

I saw [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7764/what-is-a-character) recently, and I was wondering the title of my question. Essentially is stuff like this:

```
H̠̹͖
```

A single character in reference to questions that count characters? If so, I could theoretically create a language that does any challenge in a single "character" by programming it in the zalgo areas of the character.

Comment: I assume it's cases like this which motivated the community to score by bytes rather than by characters.

Comment: @AlexA. I think it's because UTF-8 can encode 4,294,967,296 characters, and golfing langauges would use all of them.

Comment: @AlexA., I think it's more Sclipting, which was seen as deliberately abusing the previous tendency to score by characters.

Comment: The safest way to count characters is to use Twitter, because they implement the most advanced Unicode compliant character count algorithm. (btw, Twitter also counts the above as 4 chars). More info: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/counting-characters

Answer (score 23):

Again, just as I answered on the linked question, [according to a simple char/byte counting tool](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#H%CC%A0%CC%B9%CD%96), that's 4 chars, 7 bytes.

Combining diacritical marks are counted as separate Unicode characters.

Comment: It's multiple characters, and a single **grapheme cluster**. We're not counting grapheme clusters.

Answer (score 9):

## No.

A simple search shows that [combining diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) are used. These are all their own character, so `H̠̹͖` > 1 char. 
They use codepoints U+0300 to U+036F. If you have `̃.`, it has 2 Unicode codepoints -- U+002E and U+0303 -- that is definitely not 1 char.